# CoffeeScript → JavaScript の Java版はありますか?

Tags: java, compiler

CoffeeScript → JavaScript

のように
Javaを別の言語で書いて、コンパイルしたときにJavaのコードでコンパイルされるというものを探しています。

○○ → Java

こういう感じをイメージしているのですが、近いものでも良いのであれば教えていただけないでしょうか。
あと、今回、検索の仕方がわからなかったので、そういうものを調べるときのワードなども教えていただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 11):

質問ではソースコードからソースコードへのコンパイル (いわゆる、 transpiler) のことを指して
おられると思いますので、ここでは私が知るいくつかのトランスパイラの紹介と、 他に JVM 上で動く言語リストを挙げます。

CoffeeScript に一番近いのは、 [XTend](http://eclipse.org/xtend/) ではないかと考えます。わかりやすく、効率化の目的も似ています。Eclipse のサポートも硬いので試しやすいはずです。

もし、 Java 縛りで限界突破クエストへご挑戦の途中であられますのなら、わたしからは、実用重視で [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) をお勧めします。お試しください。

#### "Sourcecode-to-Sourcecode" コンパイラ

- [XTend](http://eclipse.org/xtend/)
- [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/)
- [JSP (Java Server Pages)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/jsp/index.html)
- [Haxe](http://haxe.org/)
- [Processing](https://processing.org/)

[XTend](http://eclipse.org/xtend/) は、Java 言語使用の欠点を埋めることに重点を置いた、 Java ソースコードの方言的なものになります。無理なく関数型の処理を記述でき、ソースコードの削減につながる特徴を多く持ちます。Eclipse 環境でのサポートが厚く、Class ファイルの生成前に、 Java のソースコードが生成される仕組みになっています。

[Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) は、Java の仕様にのっとった追加のアノテーション集ですが、コンパイル前に Java ソースコード生成フェイズが入るような特殊なアドオンを持っています。アクロバティックにわかりやすいソースコード生成をしてくれますので、ありきたりな繰り返しブロックを自動生成に回せます。 Getter/Setterでお悩みなら一考の価値ありです。一時期 Lambok にはお世話になりました。

良く知られている [JSP (Java Server Pages)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/jsp/index.html) は、発想としては、 HTML ページにJava コードを埋め込むものです。 Web サーバでコンパイルされる際に、内部的に醜いJavaソースコードへの変換を経ています。

[Haxe](http://haxe.org/) は、モバイルアプリを主ターゲットにした開発ツールですが、出力に Java ソースコードを持ちます。

[Processing](https://processing.org/) は、Java 言語の簡易版と言え、平べったいコードで、CGデモを書いたり、Arduino を制御できます。 プログラミングの初心者用に作られた高級言語であり、これも、コンパイル前に一度 Java のソースコードを通します。

#### "Sourcecode-to-Bytecode"　コンパイラ

また、Java ソースコードにこだわらず、 JVM の上で動く言語であれば何でもよい
ということであれば、質の高い、多くの候補があります。

- [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) / [Mirah](http://www.mirah.org/) (Ruby)
- [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/)
- [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/)
- [Clojure](http://clojure.org/) (Lisp系)
- [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) (Python)
- [Kotlin](http://kotlinlang.org/)
- [Ceylon](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceylon)
- [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Rhino) (Javascript)

バイトコードへの変換はオフトピックになりそうですから、紹介だけで説明は省きます。

Answer (score 3):

有名なところでは Clojure, Groovy, Scala あたりでしょうか。
ただJavaのコードではなくJVMのバイトコードが出力されますね。その意味ではちょっとズレてます。

検索する際は「JVM言語」もしくは「JVM上で動くプログラミング言語」みたいなキーワードを使うと良いでしょう。

Answer (score 3):

リスト型質問の気もしますが`Haxe`も`Java`コードを出力してくれます。

[Haxe/Java 入門 - Haxe](http://old.haxe.org/doc/start/java?lang=jp)

こういう情報は英語の方が多いので`generator`や`compile A into B`みたいな感じで検索すると引っかかるかもしれません。単純に`converter`でも(厳密には違う気もするけど)検索キーワードとしては引っかかる気がします。

Answer (score 2):

Java以外の言語と言っている部分が、回答として正しいかが微妙なところですが、
[Xtend](http://eclipse.org/xtend/) などが求めているものに近いものなのかな？と思います。

(一応Javaコードを吐き出してコンパイルするので)

なお[「 C# to java convertor 」 で検索](https://www.google.co.jp/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23+to+java+converter)すると、C#からJavaへ変換してくれるものなどが出てきましたよ
([CS2Jというツールがあるのを知りました](http://www.twigletsoftware.com/))

Answer (score 1):

Objective-CをJavaに変換するObjc2jというものがあるようです。
https://code.google.com/p/objc2j/

Answer (score 1):

IBMが開発したREXX言語から派生したNetRexxが、ソースをJavaソースに変換してJavaでコンパイルして
動作します。

http://www.netrexx.org/

Answer (score 1):

Fregeという言語がJavaへのソースコードトランスレータです。

http://uehaj.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/12/21/065929

Fregeは以下の特徴を持っています。
- 純関数型言語
- 非正格評価(いわゆる遅延評価)
- Hindley-Milner型推論に基づく静的型言語

[こちら](http://try.frege-lang.org/)にあるオンラインのREPLでお気軽に試すことができます。その際に、「:java」で生成されたJavaソースを見ることができます。